# When A is a point, is there any usage of >A notation besides for the 4th argument of \uput?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

In `pst-news10.pdf` on page 3-4, the author introduces a new notation `>A` where `A` is a point of any type (whether a node or simply a literal `(2,-1)`).

`>A` can be passed to the `<point>` argument  of

```
\uput{<labelsep>}[<direction angle>]{<rotation angle>}(<point>){<content>}
```

to change the behavior of `\uput` when a node is passed to its `<direction angle>` argument.

## Question

Is there any usage of `>A` besides the case given above?

In other words, does `>A` represent a new point derived from `A`? If yes, what kind of transformation applied on `A` to get the new `>A`?

In case it is just for changing the behavior of `\uput`, does it more make sense to apply `>` on `<direction angle>` rather than `<point>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other case. It is only a special rotation for a node and will not be changed.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document} 

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-0.25,-0.25)(6,5)
\pnodes(0,3){A}(3,1){B}
\psline[showpoints](A)(B)
\uput[-90](A){A}\uput[-90](B){B}
\psline[linestyle=dashed](A)(3,4)
\psline[linestyle=dashed](A)(3,5)
\psline[linestyle=dashed](A)(3,3)
\psline[linestyle=dashed](6,2)
\psline[linestyle=dashed](B)(6,1)
\psarc{->}(0,3){2.5}{0}{(3,1)}
\psarc{->}(3,1){2.5}{0}{(3,1)}
\uput*{1cm}[(B)](A){foo} \uput*{1cm}[(B)](>A){bar}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]